# Is it a truly random sample?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, normal-distribution, sample, randomness

Any hints on how to solve this problem?

> A sample  of 400 items is taken from a normal population whose mean
>   as well as variance is 4. If the sample mean is 4.5, can the sample
>   be regarded as a truly random sample?

Comment: Hint - use the t test. You know the mean and standard deviation, as well as the number of degrees of freedom. Compute the t statistic and decide if the p value is low enough to reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: Further hint - the standard error of the mean of a sample is $\sigma / \sqrt{N}$. So your sample mean is 5 standard errors from the population mean. How likely is that for a random sample?

Comment: Please improve the title of your question, so it will be meaningful to people who browse lists of questions here.

Comment: @Floris (1) The population variance is known, not estimated, so a t-test would be unsuitable even if this was a testing situation. Those are for when the standard deviation is estimated. $\quad$ (2) In any case, the question is *not* answered by hypothesis tests of any kind. $\quad$ Your first comment is not helpful.

Comment: @Glen_b I was thinking whether this can be proceeded by testing. Suppose we test H0 : mu = 4 vs. H1 : mu not= 4. Now we find the confidence interval for mu.  If the C.I. does not contain 4 then I may conclude that the sample is not random.
But will this conclusion right ?

Comment: Boral, that is a reasonable approach. Note that it would not use a Student t-test, though, because you do not know the sample variance. It would involve the (simpler) z-test, for which you use the known population variance. Mathematically that is equivalent to the test @Harvey Motulsky suggested in his answer.  (There is no practical difference between the t-test and the z-test with this sample of 400 items. We should nevertheless care about the distinction because it is more important to understand the logic of the procedures than to get some kind of "right" answer.)

Comment: @boral The question you asked in your post is "is it a truly random sample?". The question addressed by hypothesis tests or CIs in your comment is somewhat different - it answers a question about consistency of the sample with the distribution you'd get with random sampling from the population distribution. Failure to reject that doesn't imply 'truly random sampling' - you can have nonrandom sampling that is nevertheless not rejected (e.g. some very systematic sampling might be highly representative - by design). But Harvey pretty much covers that issue (what tests/CIs tell us) in his answer.

Comment: @Glen_b You are right. Failure to reject does not imply truely random sample. I think this question cannot be answered with the help of statistics, as Harvey has already said.

But I wonder is there any method or way not necessarily statistical which answers this type of questions ?

Comment: Actually, it is standard practice to test pseudorandom number generators (or any purported random number generator) by applying a large battery of hypothesis tests. See Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming* Section 3.3 or look at the [Diehard tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests), for instance. In these applications, although it is usually known exactly how the sample is created, hypothesis tests are used to detect deviations from various behaviors expected of random samples. That seems like a useful framework in which to view the present question.

Comment: @whuber But in order to apply these battery of tests I need to know the sample values isn't it ? But I know only sample mean and not the sample values. So I think I cannot apply Diehard tests. Am I correct ?

Comment: The Diehard tests are irrelevant to these particular data. However, one of the Diehard tests evaluates whether the mean of a sequence deviates from its expectation by more than would be explained by random variation. That's what you are doing here.  Thus, your test--although simple and by no means an entire battery of tests--could be viewed from this perspective as being a partial test of randomness. This helps us interpret @Glen_b's assertion (2), which I believe was intended to mean that no hypothesis tests can demonstrate randomness--but some can demonstrate *lack* of randomness.

Comment: @whuber that was indeed the intent

Comment: @whuber Can you please say in details how to do the test you are speaking of. I don't know much about Diehard tests.

Comment: Sikkim Manipal Assignment Question?? I have the Answer.

Comment: Is this for a class assignment? If so, please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its wiki.

Answer (score 6):

Statistical calculations can answer this question:  IF you collected many random samples, in what fraction would the mean be as far (or further) from the population mean as you observed? If the answer is tiny, you might suspect that the sample was not random.

But statistical calculations cannot answer the question: Was this a random sample? The only way to know that is to find out how the sampling was done.

Answer (score 3):

A Monte Carlo solution (in Python), along the lines of @Harvey's response:

```
import numpy as np
# 10,0000 random samples from you population
samples = [np.random.normal(loc=4, scale=4, size=400) for i in range(100000)]
# Mean of each sample
means = np.array([np.mean(sample) for sample in samples])
# How many of these means are greater than 4.5?
tested = means > 4.5
np.mean(tested)

Out[11]: 0.0064000000000000003
```

So out of 10,0000 samples, only 0.64%, or 640, had a mean greater than 4.5. Therefore, the probability of getting such a high mean from a random sample is $p = .0064$.

> Caveat: I could be wrong. Discussion welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the sample variance is also $4$ (since I believe we need to the sample variance to solve this, please correct me if I'm wrong), the standard error of the sample mean would be $2/\sqrt{400}=0.1$. Since the population mean is $4$, using a t-test we get $t=(4.5-4)/0.1=5$, which is well within standard ranges of rejection values of the null hypothesis (that the sample mean is equal to the population mean).